# :last-child is not being recognized

Tags: jquery

I have a scroll to function that I need to execute to scroll to the last message in its container, which is the container with chunk_id. The problem is that it works as is for going to the container, but if I add last-child into the mix the function does not work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**Works**

```
$.scrollTo('div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"]', 800, {easing:'elasout',offset:-250} );
```

**Does not**

```
$.scrollTo('div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"]:last-child', 800, {easing:'elasout',offset:-250} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to find the last child element of the `div`.  Your code is currently selecting the last `div` with a particular `chunk_id` that is also the last child of its parent. This may well not exist.

You should use the [child selector `>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector) combined with `:last-child` to find the last child element of the element already selected:

```
$.scrollTo('div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"] > :last-child', 800, {easing:'elasout',offset:-250} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find the `:last-child` *inside of* the `div`, using the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
'div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"] > :last-child'
```

Your code applies the `:last-child` filter to the `div` selector itself, so it only matches elements which are both `div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"]` *and* `:last-child`.